# How to write a preamble for latex files (in French) shared between MacOS, Linux and Windows?

Tags: packages, windows, input-encodings, linux, macos

I'm in charge of a database of scientific exercises (>1000) written in french (UTF8 encoding) and sharing a single preamble.

Those exercises can be edited and compiled (pdflatex) by various users with different OSes (Windows, MacOS, Linux).

Every now and then on Windows, I get problems related with French accents which lead to incomprehensible errors hard to detect for most users (such as missing $) while the same files compile fine on MacOS and Linux

I now wonder about the best package and practices for latex files written in French shared between those OSes.

Here is the beginning of my current preamble :

```
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\RequirePackage[utf8]{inputenc} % a adapter si autre que pdflatex
\RequirePackage[english,main=french]{babel}
```

Before, I used

```
\RequirePackage[utf8x]{inputenc} % a adapter si autre que pdflatex
\RequirePackage[english,main=french]{babel}
```

and had even more problems on Windows such as missing $ and so on (I work with subimport)

Comment: utf8 should work fine. You should  show a concrete example that fails.

Comment: You can use Xelatex

Comment: @rpapa probably not actually. The problem files will not be in UTF-8 but some legacy windows encoding, so they will not work at all with xelatex (and if re-encoded to utf-8 they will work with all tex flavours)

Comment: this will be unrelated to windows/linux but to the file encoding. If they are in utf-8 then they should work with current latex  with no inputenc at all or with older latex with `\usepackage[utf8]{inutpenc}` if they are in latin1 legacy encoding then you could use your editor to re-save the file as utf-8 or specify the encoding to latex with `\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}` You may find latin1 (iso-8859-1) files on windows or linux.

Comment: All files are encoding in UTF8 (even those produced on Windows). So `\usepackage[utf8]{inutpenc}` is better than `\usepackage[utf8x]{inutpenc}` for multi-OSes purpose ?

Comment: In a current latex utf8 is the default and you don't need anything. In older latex use utf8.

Comment: While there’s nothing wrong with using the older toolchain, there’s also no reason not to just use Unicode for everything, in LuaLaAteX, if you don’t have a publisher forcing you to stick with PDFTeX.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem some time ago. As it turned out, the issue was not LateX but the editor. When editing from different platforms or editors, make sure that each user is saving their files in the same encoding. In my editors: TeXstudio and Texworks, it's at the bottom right of the editor: It has to indicate UTF-8.

Answer (score 0):

UTF-8 will be compatible between all of them, but it’s possible you have existing files stored in different formats (CP1252, Mac-Roman, ISO-8859-15, etc.) If you can’t save or convert everything as UTF-8, one workaround is to use `selinput`.  This should be able to read your source files regardless of their encoding.

The incompatibility I ran into most recently (which broke a document of mine that used `cmathbb` for someone else on Linux) is that filenames are case-sensitive on Linux, but case-insensitive on Windows. Be sure that all your filenames work on both case-sensitive and case-insensitive OSes.

The fontname lookups on `fontspec` are another source of potential incompatibility between OSes, and also between XeTeX and LuaTeX. In particular, fonts installed locally for a single user work on Linux, but not Windows or Mac.  The safest approach is to use either a `.fontspec` file, or specify the exact filenames with, for example,

```
\defaultfontfeatures[LibertinusSans]{
  UprightFont = *-Regular ,
  BoldFont = *-Bold ,
  ItalicFont = *-Italic ,
  BoldItalicFont = *-BoldItalic ,
  Extension = .otf }
\setsansfont{LibertinusSans}
```

If you’re using font packages, however, they should do all the work for you.